# How can I use Perl libraries from PHP?

Tags: php, perl, embed

I want to use Perl libraries from a PHP application. I have heard that it is possible.

I have considered the possibility of re-writing the libraries in PHP, but I do not think that is a good idea because it is difficult.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could also use [PHP::Interpreter](http://search.cpan.org/~aff/PHP-Interpreter-1.0.2/lib/PHP/Interpreter.pm) from CPAN. This allows you to embed a PHP interpreter in Perl and also, more usefully for you, to create a Perl object in PHP:

```
<?php
    $perl = Perl::getInstance();
    $fh = $perl->new("IO::File", "<$file");
    while($fh->getline()) {
      # ...
    }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Inline::PHP CPAN module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Inline/) from Perl to integrate PHP code (just use library and call you your PHP code). Or you can use [perl PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/perl) to call Perl from PHP.

In future you will be able to use Parrot virtual machine to use libraries from any supported language. Parrot supports this, but Perl 5 and [PHP support in Parrot](http://wiki.github.com/bschmalhofer/pipp) is weak.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the PECL extension - I'd go that way I suspect.

Comment: `perl PECL extension` installation is not user friendly and has problems for php 5.2+