# Most efficient way to call Perl Libraries from within PHP?

Tags: php, perl, libraries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use Perl libraries from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030736/how-can-i-use-perl-libraries-from-php)

I would like to make use of some libraries only available in Perl from my PHP applications. I haven't used Perl before but have been looking into it some and am still not sure of the best way to do this.. it seems a lot of the resources I found online were pretty old that dealt with this, I believe I saw a project that makes doing this easier, but once again, it seemed that it might no longer be active so I'm a bit hesitant to "dive in" to it..

I would appreciate any advice on this.. thanks

Comment: I believe this has been asked several times already...

Comment: ok sorry, guess my searches missed it