# Use Ruby in PHP programs

Tags: php, ruby, programming-languages

I saw a lot of interesting libraries in Ruby that don't exist for PHP or its equivalents, so I want know if there is a library interpreter or something that can use RUBY code inside PHP programs to call methods and pass variables.

thx

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. I wanted to invite you to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) so that you know how to ask and answer questions (this also is a reaction to your answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1030736/468327)). Further please respect our community by using good spelling and grammar and people will be happy to help you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way that I know of to, say, write a PHP wrapper for a Ruby class.

You can, however, write a standalone Ruby script and then call it with a [`system`](http://php.net/system) command.

Comment: yea but hte interesting is pass varibals from one to ohter

Comment: Well, then write your standalone ruby script to accept parameters on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a Ruby daemon or background worker of some kind and connect it with something like RabbitMQ.

But [Matchu's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107415/matchu) suggestion of a script should be good enough. Ruby starts quickly. A good server can start Ruby from scratch and run a trivial Ruby script almost 500 times / second / core. Even a bad server can do 50 / second.